# Sitecore Creating Item with Fields[] Included

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

I want to create an item to sitecore using code behind.

I found this piece of code and it works perfectly fine.

```
public void CreateItem(String itmName)
{
    //Again we need to handle security
    //In this example we just disable it
    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        //First get the parent item from the master database
        Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        Item parentItem = masterDb.Items["/sitecore/content/SOHO/Settings/Metadata/Project"];


        //Now we need to get the template from which the item is created
        TemplateItem template = masterDb.GetTemplate("SOHO/Misc/Project");
        //Now we can add the new item as a child to the parent
        parentItem.Add(itmName, template);


        //We can now manipulate the fields and publish as in the previous example
    }
}
```

But I want to fill in the fields also. like..

```
Item.Fields["test"].Value="testing";
```

For that I found out how to edit an item

```
public void AlterItem()
{
  //Use a security disabler to allow changes
  using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
  {
    //You want to alter the item in the master database, so get the item from there
    Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    Item item = db.Items["/sitecore/content/home"];


    //Begin editing
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    try
    {
      //perform the editing
      item.Fields["Title"].Value = "This value will be stored";
    }
    finally
    {
      //Close the editing state
      item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how to combine those 2 things.

I think of 2 methods.

**Method 1**

Grab the `ID` of the `Item` that I created.

I can grab the `Name` but `Name` might be duplicated.

**Method 2**

Fill in the fields before creating the `Item`

But then.. again I have no idea how to do those 2 methods.

I would be appreciated if I can get some tips.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that good practice is generally to use Item IDs rather than paths. That way your code is not dependent on your IA in the content tree. I think generally performance is also better using native IDs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method **item.Add()** returns the created item so your code should look like this:

```
    Item newItem = parent.Add(itemName, template);
    newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
    newItem.Fields["fieldName"].Value = "fieldValue";
    newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: You can also make this more error proof like so:  
`using(new EditContext(newItem))  
{  
// change fields here  
}`

Comment: @KamFigy I think this post still applies. http://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2006/04/03/new-way-of-editing-items/  It may be ancient, but I've never seen EditContext being officially recommended since this time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code which you can use to [Create items programmatically based on template in sitecore](https://itsmycode.com/create-items-programmatically-based-template-sitecore/).

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;    
// The SecurityDisabler is required which will overrides the current security model, allowing the code
// to access the item without any security. 
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
  // Get the master database
  Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master");
  // Get the template for which you need to create item
  Items.TemplateItem template = master.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item");
 
  // Get the place in the site tree where the new item must be inserted
  Item parentItem = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
 
  // Add the item to the site tree
  Item newItem = parentItem.Add("NameOfNewItem", template);
 
  // Set the new item in editing mode
  // Fields can only be updated when in editing mode
  // (It's like the begin transaction on a database)
  newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
  try
  {
    // Assign values to the fields of the new item
    newItem.Fields["Title"].Value = "NewValue1";
    newItem.Fields["Text"].Value = "NewValue2";
 
    // End editing will write the new values back to the Sitecore
    // database (It's like commit transaction of a database)
    newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    // Log the message on any failure to sitecore log
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Could not update item " + newItem.Paths.FullPath + ": " + ex.Message, this);
 
    // Cancel the edit (not really needed, as Sitecore automatically aborts
    // the transaction on exceptions, but it wont hurt your code)
    newItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
  }
}
```